# Configure jt400 xa-datasource in JBoss EAP 7 standalone.xml

Tags: jboss, db2, datasource, xa, jt400

I have as400 driver file (jt400.jar) in c:\jboss-EAP7\modules\com\ibm\main\ with the corresponding module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ibm">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jt400.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Here is the datasource configuration in my standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
            <datasources>
                <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/ds/DB2DataSource" pool-name="ds/DB2DataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true"> 
                    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                        xxx.xx.xxx.x
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <driver>as400</driver>
                    <xa-pool>
                        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                        <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
                        <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                        <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                        <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                    </xa-pool>                       
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>pass</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </xa-datasource>
                <drivers>
                   <driver name="as400" module="com.ibm">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

I have the following problem in the datasource binding:

```
15:44:00,482 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("xa-data-source" => "ds/DB2DataSource")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/ds/DB2DataSource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.as400]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.ds/DB2DataSource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.as400]"
]}
15:44:00,485 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("xa-data-source" => "ds/DB2DataSource")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/ds/DB2DataSource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.as400]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.ds/DB2DataSource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.as400]",
    "org.wildfly.data-source.ds/DB2DataSource is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.as400]"
]}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please note that the connection is successful with the same parameters when using a SQLClient (e.g. DBeaver).

Thanks

Comment: Try add `<xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>` in your datasource definition.

Comment: I tried adding the line you suggested, but it still doesn't work (same error). Have you any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this on module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.ibm.as400">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="jt400-10.2.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

And this on standalone.xml

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="jt400" module="com.ibm.as400">
            <driver-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver-class>
            <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   </driver>
</drivers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the *XML declaration* from the `module.xml` file.

I have replicated your configuration and I found that after removing the first line of the `module.xml` file the errors don't appear anymore.